# Order by two columns regarding their relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I want to order the following things by their Ordernum (unique) regarding the RefID (which holds the same products together) with SQL on a Oracle Database:

**It has to be first ordered by OrderNum followed by every product with the same RefID. The row with the lowest OrderNum should be first, then the products with the same RefID, after that the next higher OrderNum and so on...**

```
OrderNum    |   RefID   | ID
10          |   100     | 8
1           |   200     | 9
2           |   100     | 4
8           |   200     | 12
3           |   200     | 20
0           |   10      | 11
```

What I tried and what gives me just the result ordered by OrderNum, not regarding the same RefIDs:

```
SELECT * FROM products
ORDER BY OrderNum, RefID
```

Expected result

```
0           |   10      | 11
1           |   200     | 9
3           |   200     | 20
8           |   200     | 12
2           |   100     | 4
10          |   100     | 8
```

I think this has to be done with a subselect, right? But how does this look like?

Comment: Typo? Row 1, 300, 4 exists in sample data, but not in the ordered result...

Comment: @jarlh: I updated the question because I think I asked the wrong way. Maybe its now clear what I expect.

Comment: So, the row with the lowest `OrderNum` should be first. The next row(s) should then be all of the rows with the same `RefID` value, all sorted by `OrderNum`. After that set of rows, the next row should be a row with a different `RefID` and the lowest `OrderNum` that hasn't yet appeared?

Comment: Yes, first lowest Ordernum, then the related products with the same RefID, then the next higher Ordernum...

Comment: So a row with `4, 150, 10`, if added to your sample, should come last (and would help to demonstrate why the existing simple `ORDER` solutions aren't correct)

Comment: You've added another sample, but it's another sample where the simple `ORDER` solutions *also* produce your expected results. That's why I suggested one which *wouldn't*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I added more data and updated the SQL Fiddle

Comment: @frgtv10: You chose the wrong DBMS in your fiddle (MySQL instead of Oracle). Use this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e86d/1 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Oracle supports CTE and window functions, so something like the following should work:

```
WITH Extras as (
   SELECT
       p.*,
       MIN(OrderNum) OVER (PARTITION BY RefID) as LowNum,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RefID ORDER BY OrderNum) as rn
   FROM
       Products p
)
SELECT * from Extras ORDER BY LowNum,rn;
```

Common Table Expressions (CTEs) are similar to subqueries but I tend to prefer to use them, all other things being equal - there's no specific advantage in this query, but they *can* be reused multiple times, and they can easily build on previous ones without introducing lots of nesting.

Comment: Amazing that you figured out what is actually being wanted. I think in Oracle you'd have to use a qualifier for the asterix, so as not to say "give me all plus something". Hence: `SELECT Products.*, MIN(OrderNum) ...`. You can also get rid of ROW_NUMBER and order by `LowNum, RefID, OrderNum` directly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I've added an alias which I hope should work. I'll leave the ROW_NUMBER for now since I think it helps to document what's wanted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you that you helped me to clearified what I wanted, it feels difficult for me to ask the correct way. Can you add it to the current SQL-Fiddle? I think SQL-Fiddle has a problem with the "WITH" Part... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cfd7/4

Comment: Can there be two RefIDs with the same MIN(OrderNum)? Then it wouldn't suffice to sort by `LowNum,rn`and you'd need `LowNum,RefID,rn`or `LowNum, RefID, OrderNum`for that matter. (Or determine rn differently: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RefID, OrderNum) as rn`.)

Comment: @frgtv10 - you're question is tagged [tag:oracle] but your fiddle is using [tag:mysql]. If your question is about mysql, please re-tag it and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oracle is correct, I thought SQL Fiddle can handle this.

Comment: @frgtv10 - it can, but you have to select which product you're using from the drop-down at the top. Currently it's using MySQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Amazing, it works. Thank you. I now have check how you made it.

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by OrderNum and inside each OrderNum by RefID, but what you want to do is just the opposite, i.e. to order by RefID first and inside each RefID by OrderNum:

```
SELECT * FROM products
ORDER BY RefID, OrderNum;
```

Comment: I updated the question because I think I asked the wrong way. Maybe its now clear what I expect.

Comment: I must admit that I didn't until Damien_The_Unbeliever clarified that :-) I suppose that his answer solves your problem finally.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RefID` and `OrderNum` to order by your result. Use `ASC` and `DESC` for proper ordering (default is `ASC`):

```
select * from products
order by RefID DESC,OrderNum ASC
```

Result:

```
OrderNum    RefID   ID
-----------------------
1           200     9
3           200     20
8           200     12
2           100     4
10          100     8
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5239/2)

Comment: I updated the question because I think I asked the wrong way. Maybe its now clear what I expect.

Comment: @frgtv10: Updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: this will work for the described data, right. But if you now will add (0, 10, 11) in your Fiddle, it will not work again.

Comment: I updatet the SQL Fiddle in the question and added more data.

Answer (score 0):

you want to Ordernum regarding the RefID ,i think it may gives result according you:-

```
     select * from products
     order by RefID,OrderNum
```

Comment: I updated the question because I think I asked the wrong way. Maybe its now clear what I expect.